"'BillInvoice' instance needs to have a primary key value before this relationship can be used" Error
I'm experiencing an issue with my Django project where I'm trying to create a BillInvoice and its associated BillLineItem instances. The error I'm encountering is:
"'BillInvoice' instance needs to have a primary key value before this relationship can be used"
Context:
I have a form view (CreateInvoiceView) that handles the creation of invoices and their line items using a formset. The relevant parts of my code are as follows:
This is my model.py
Userprofile
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ROLE = [
        ('Select Role', 'Select Role'),
        ('Admin', 'Admin'),
        ('CBUMT', 'CBUMT'),
        ('Pharmacist', 'Pharmacist'),
        ('Doctor', 'Doctor'),
        ('Nurse', 'Nurse'),
        ('Referral Provider', 'Referral Provider'),
        ('Member', 'Memeber'),
        ('Dependent', 'Dependent'),
    ]

    GENDER = [
        ('None', 'None'),
        ('Male', 'Male'),
        ('Female', 'Female'),
        
    ]
    
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    is_medical_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=ROLE, default='CBUMT')
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=GENDER, default='None')
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank= False, null=False, default=timezone.now)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to='images/', default='img/placeholder.jpg')

    @property
    def age(self):
        today = date.today()
        age = today.year - self.date_of_birth.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (self.date_of_birth.month, self.date_of_birth.day))
        return age

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + ' | ' + self.role

**BillInvoice**

class BillInvoice(models.Model):
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('Medicine', 'Medicine'),
        ('Auxillary', 'Auxillary'),
        ('Mixed', 'Mixed'),
    ]
    patient = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoices', null=True)
    invoice_type = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TYPE_CHOICES, default='Medicine')
    reference = models.ForeignKey(Referral, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='invoice_references', null=True)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    due_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    prepared_by = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='prepared_invoices', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Invoice for {self.patient} on {self.date}'
    
    def update_amount(self):
        total_amount = sum(item.amount for item in self.lineitems.all())
        self.amount = total_amount

    def get_status(self):
        return self.status

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id and not self.due_date:
            self.due_date = datetime.now() + timedelta(days=30)
        self.update_amount()  # Update the amount before saving
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

BillLineItem
class BillLineItem(models.Model):
    patient = models.ForeignKey(BillInvoice, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lineitems')
    service = models.TextField()
    description = models.TextField()
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.patient)

M views.py
CreateInvoiceView
class CreateInvoiceView(FormView):
    template_name = 'referral/invoice_create.html'
    form_class = BillInvoiceForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ereferral:invoice-list')  # Adjust as needed

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = LineItemFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['formset'] = LineItemFormset()
        context['title'] = "Invoice Generator"
        context['heading_message'] = 'Formset Demo'
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']

        if formset.is_valid():
            # Retrieve the UserProfile instance
            patient_profile = form.cleaned_data.get("patient")  # Assuming this returns a UserProfile instance
            
            # Save the BillInvoice instance to get the primary key
            invoice = BillInvoice(
                patient=patient_profile,  # Assuming 'patient' is a ForeignKey to UserProfile
                invoice_type=form.cleaned_data["invoice_type"],
                reference=form.cleaned_data["reference"],
                amount=0  # Initial total_amount, will update later
            )
            invoice.save()  # Now the invoice instance has a primary key

            total = 0
            for item_form in formset:
                if item_form.cleaned_data:  # Ensure the form is not empty
                    service = item_form.cleaned_data.get('service')
                    description = item_form.cleaned_data.get('description')
                    quantity = item_form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
                    rate = item_form.cleaned_data.get('rate')
                    if service and description and quantity and rate:
                        amount = float(rate) * float(quantity)
                        total += amount
                        BillLineItem.objects.create(
                            invoice=invoice,  # Associating the line item with the invoice
                            service=service,
                            description=description,
                            quantity=quantity,
                            rate=rate,
                            amount=amount
                        )

            # Update the total amount of the invoice after creating all line items
            invoice.total_amount = total
            invoice.save()

            try:
                generate_PDF(self.request, id=invoice.id)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"PDF generation error: {e}")

            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        logger.error("Form or formset is invalid")
        logger.error("Form errors: %s", form.errors)
        logger.error("Formset errors: %s", formset.errors)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))
    


# Define the formset outside the view class to avoid redefinition
LineItemFormset = formset_factory(LineItemForm, extra=1)

Error Details:
I am encountering the error when trying to save the BillLineItem instances. It seems that the BillInvoice instance does not have a primary key assigned before attempting to create the BillLineItem instances.
Request:
Could someone please help me identify what might be going wrong? Specifically:

Is there an issue with how I’m handling the saving of the BillInvoice instance?

Are there any adjustments needed in my view or model definitions to ensure the BillInvoice instance is saved with a primary key before associating BillLineItem instances?


What I Have Tried:
Saving the Invoice Immediately: I made sure to save the BillInvoice instance immediately after creating it, so it gets a primary key assigned before attempting to create any BillLineItem instances. This should ensure the invoice has an ID when it's referenced by the line items.
CreateInvoiceView
class CreateInvoiceView(FormView):
    template_name = 'referral/invoice_create.html'
    form_class = BillInvoiceForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ereferral:invoice-list')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            context['formset'] = LineItemFormset(self.request.POST)
        else:
            context['formset'] = LineItemFormset()
        context['title'] = "Invoice Generator"
        context['heading_message'] = 'Formset Demo'
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']

        if formset.is_valid():
            try:
                # Save the BillInvoice instance
                invoice = form.save(commit=False)
                patient_profile = form.cleaned_data.get("patient")
                invoice.patient = patient_profile
                invoice.total_amount = 0  # Initialize total amount
                invoice.save()

                # Log the invoice primary key to ensure it is saved
                logger.debug(f"Invoice saved with ID: {invoice.id}")

                total = 0
                for item_form in formset:
                    if item_form.cleaned_data:
                        service = item_form.cleaned_data.get('service')
                        description = item_form.cleaned_data.get('description')
                        quantity = item_form.cleaned_data.get('quantity')
                        rate = item_form.cleaned_data.get('rate')
                        if service and description and quantity and rate:
                            amount = float(rate) * float(quantity)
                            total += amount
                            BillLineItem.objects.create(
                                invoice=invoice,
                                service=service,
                                description=description,
                                quantity=quantity,
                                rate=rate,
                                amount=amount
                            )

                # Update the total amount of the invoice after creating all line items
                invoice.total_amount = total
                invoice.save()

                try:
                    generate_PDF(self.request, id=invoice.id)
                except Exception as e:
                    logger.error(f"PDF generation error: {e}")

                return super().form_valid(form)
            except Exception as e:
                logger.error(f"Error saving invoice or line items: {e}")
                return self.form_invalid(form)
        else:
            logger.error("Formset is invalid")
            logger.error(formset.errors)
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        context = self.get_context_data()
        formset = context['formset']
        logger.error("Form or formset is invalid")
        logger.error("Form errors: %s", form.errors)
        logger.error("Formset errors: %s", formset.errors)
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))


did you find any solution? me too I am facing exactly the same problem

I am still working around

I am facing the same problem the solution that I was able to implement is to save the instance when initiating the create view form
I am using Wagtail so it is little bit different from Django but I think you can do same when initiating the form.
here the sample of the code:
class CreateInvoiceView(FormView):

    def __init__(self, *args: list, **kwargs: dict) -> None:
        if not kwargs["instance"].pk:
            invoice = kwargs["instance"]
            invoice.save()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

